# WHERE Clause in nested json data Laravel 5

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

As a follow up question in my last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388764/return-logic-from-controller-into-view-laravel-5), I just can't figure out how to use `WHERE` clause when you have a nested `json` data. Please see my last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388764/return-logic-from-controller-into-view-laravel-5) as reference to this.

So, I have this kind of data generated by using relationship in my models:

```
[
  {
     "id":1,
     "name":"South Luzon",
     "branches":[
        {
           "id":1,
           "machinenum":108,
           "name":"Alaminos",
           "region_id":1,
           "user":{
              "id":52,
              "name":"",
              "email":"baic@alaminosbranch.addessacorp",
              "role":0,
              "machinenum":108,
              "created_at":"2016-07-11 05:58:04",
              "updated_at":"2016-07-14 09:49:00",
              "pendings":[
                 {
                    "id":10,
                    "user_id":52,
                    "region":"South Luzon",
                    "branch":"Alaminos",
                    "docdate":"2016-07-14 00:00:00",
                    "ls_or":12345,
                    "por":1,
                    "ls_ci":12345,
                    "ci":2,
                    "ls_ch":12345,
                    "ch":2,
                    "dep":5,
                    "cla":0,
                    "grpo":3,
                    "si":25,
                    "so":62,
                    "sts":2,
                    "disb":3,
                    "arcm":5,
                    "apcm":65,
                    "pint":2,
                    "rc_cash":1,
                    "reason":"Test Reason Alaminos",
                    "created_at":"2016-07-14 09:48:55",
                    "updated_at":"2016-07-14 09:48:55"
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is loop all `regions` with `branches` and get the `pending` of each branches. I'm successfully done the looping with my last [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388764/return-logic-from-controller-into-view-laravel-5). Now, I just want to filter the date when the `pending` was created.

I'm  trying to do this:

```
$regions = Region::with(array('branches->user->pendings' => function($query) {
    $query->where('created_at', '=', '2016-07-14 09:48:55');
}))->get();
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::branches->user->pendings()
```

I've also done some research but end up asking here. Thanks in advance and please don't forget to see my last [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388764/return-logic-from-controller-into-view-laravel-5) as your reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code seems to work:

```
$regions = Region::with(['branches.user.pendings' => function($query){
    $query->where('created_at', 'like', '%2016-07-12%');
}])->get();
```

Please confirm if it is a best practice or there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regions = App\Region::with(['pendings' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('created_at', '=', '2016-07-14 09:48:55');

}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do this on the relationships first before you output it in json? You can build this query there so the json output will be clean. Your previous post has an answer that may lead you to the solution.

Comment: The date in my question is just an example. Obviously, the date would be in a variable like `$filter_date = '2016-07-14'`. And probably, that data has only been retrieved in the `view` using `<input>` or `<select>` tags and pass it to the `controller` for handling and building logics.

Comment: I know. When you do the relationships say:

function branches(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Branch')->with('usermachines')->where('field', 'value');
}

You can already do that in the model so the output will be clean.

Comment: Oh I see. But how can I pass the variable `date` into my model through controller? Any idea?

Comment: Then you can create method inside that model and call it in your controller with the `date` as the parameter? Tama? :P

Comment: Haha. Panu ko pero ipapasa ung date galing `controller` papuntang `model`?

Comment: This page has been removed!